# Mandatory and NON-Mandatory Field in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g, bi-publisher

I have two parameter for a SQL query as shown below

```
Select * from table1 where :B in B and (:C in C or :C is null)
```

**Requirement:**

:B is a mandatory Field.if this value is null no record will be displayed

but :C is non mandatory Field.if this value is null then all record that satisfy the condition for :B is displayed.

**Note:** Multiply Selection is required For :B and :C

**Problem:**

if :C is null then it works fine.
if the :C is given only one value as input then also it works fine.But when multiply Value is passed it not working as expected.its showing 'Failed to Load XMl' error in BI publisher

am using this query in BI publisher.i want to solve the problem in SQL level itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is syntax is correct.

```
select * from
(
    select 'A1' A, 'B1' B, 'C1' C from dual
    union
    select 'A2' A, 'B2' B, '' C from dual
    union
    select 'A3' A, 'B3' B, 'C3' C from dual)
where B in('B1', 'B2')
and(C in('C1', 'C2') or C is null)
```

You will have to see if BIP is wrongly constructing the SQL.  Enable BI logs and try to extract the final SQL being run, that will give you the issue.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/Reports/troubleshooting4.html
http://bichaos.blogspot.com/2011/02/bi-publisher-11g-log-files-location.html